# IAM Role setup enabled to create databases and tables with Lake Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-lake-formation

What would be the setup of an IAM Role, that can be used by some service to create databases and tables and also query that tables, when Lake Formation is enabled, **after** revoking SUPER form the IAMAllowedPrincipals group?
The AWS recommended IAM Policy, attached to such a role did not work:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "GlueFullReadAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lakeformation:GetDataAccess",
            "glue:GetTable",
            "glue:GetTables",
            "glue:SearchTables",
            "glue:GetDatabase",
            "glue:GetDatabases",
            "glue:GetPartitions"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `GlueFullReadAccess` Policy only allows read access. It doesn’t provide write permissions. To be able to create databases, tables, and partitions, you need to add the respective permissions as well.

Please have a look at the [AWS Glue API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api.html) to see the available actions.

Comment: And I need to do that on IAM layer? What I try to avoid is granting permissions for existing role to every new database and new table from Lake Formation.